# Trying to install Ubuntu on Mac mini, got a bit stuck

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mac

I already have a Ubuntu installation on an old Dell Latitude and thought I would try on a Mac mini, but have got stuck.

What I tried :

- Created a partition
- Disabled SIP (Restarted in recovery mode, entered 'csrutil disable')
- Installed rEFInd
- Selected USB Drive and installed Ubuntu

All worked as instructions.
After installing some apps and trying a few more things such as automatically mounting an external drive it wouldn't boot.
Couldn't get going, error messages indicate drive might be corrupt. No problem - I'll just start again.

Where I am now:

As I couldn't get back to my Mac O/S

- I did a PRAM reset
- Booted into Mac o/s
- Attempted to reinstall rEFInd, but told me SIP was enabled
- Restarted in recovery mode, entered 'csrutil disable' and rebooted
- Upon reboot I have the GRUB command. No rEFInd boot menu, no Mac O/S

I can't figure out how to get out of the GRUB command (typing 'normal' has no effect) and into the boot loader menu.

The hardware is a Mac Mini late 2013. 250gb SSD with 177Gb for my Ubuntu partition. There's no data on the drive that I need.

Any help or direction would be gratefully received thank you

Ben

Comment: Have I asked in the right section? Can anyone help with some pointers Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Ubuntu is compatible with the Mac Startup Manager. You do not need to install rEFInd. Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> at startup. Continue to hold down the key until the Startup Manager icons appears. To boot Ubuntu, select arrow below the icon labeled "EFI Boot". To make an operating system the default, you need to hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key before making your selection.

If you still wish to use rEFInd, the post a comment and I can give some additional help.